if my wife remarries after i die, who will i get? And what if my wish was to have my wife exclusively in the hereafter (Jannah)?
In islam, it's said that a wife will be with her last husband from earth in paradise (most popular belief), but what about the previous husband if he was good to his wife and sincerely prayed and wanted to be with his wife in the hereafter? Will Allah grant his wish in paradise if he wishes for exclusivity with his wife ? Whether it be by means of alternate reality or whatever possibilities? Or will he get a different spouse? And if yes to a different spouse, then isn't paradise very limited to what we want as Allah has promised believers will get whatever they wish for?
I am aware he might remove haram wishes/desires, but asking to be with my spouse eternally is not a haram wish and he promises that spouses will be together or people will be together with their loved ones.
If one says, "oh you won't feel negativity if you see your wife with her last husband, there won't be any rivalry or enmity, etc", but that's brainwashing in this case and it's not my genuine wish to watch my wife be with someone else, rather Allah is enforcing everything according to his wishes. I pray to Allah to forgive me if i had said anything blasphemous or bad. That is not my intention.
Personally, i have always wanted a righteous wife and a marriage that will last eternally in case i make it to Jannah. In this life and the hereafter. If despite knowing this, Allah brainwashes me, that according to my limited knowledge, is not fair. I don't personally want to invest in a marriage which has a possibility for me to love someone deeply and pray to be together in the hereafter but due to my untimely passing, she has to remarry and belong to someone else eternally. It is very disturbing to me to even think about.
I would be grateful if i can get a proper answer for this. Thank you!

Refer to Can a man choose not to be with his wife in the afterlife? and When a woman's husband dies and she remarries, which husband will she be with in Jannah?
If your wife remarries then there are different views on which man will be her husband in paradise. They include:

She will be given a choice
She will be with the husband who had treated her better in this world
She will be with her last husband
If the husbands were equally good to her then she will be given to the last one. Otherwise she will be given a choice and will choose the one who treated her better

If you do not get your old earthly wife in paradise then you will be satisfied with your wives from the Hoor al-Ayn or any other human wives you may be married to in paradise.
You will get in paradise what you desire then - not necessarily what you desire currently. Further, in paradise you will only desire what is proper.
What one desires in this world can have the following problems:

Desires which are mutually exclusive. For example you might desire to be with your wife but your wife might despise you, or her second husband might also desire to have her. Whose wish will be fulfilled? Why should your desires be given preference over the desires of your wife or her second husband?

Desires which are against fitrah. For example one might desire homosexuality, or to be married to his own mother etc. Should these desires be allowed and fulfilled in paradise? If not then how is your desire any different, as you desire to obtain the wife of another man which is immoral.


Your case is similar, your desire has a conflict of interest and is improper. The husband given to your wife will be according to Allah's Judgement. Your dislike of it is of no importance, although you should learn submission to Allah's will if you wish to enter paradise.

Thank you for your kind answer. I have come to terms with it.
